# Are the leaves on my Fatsia Japonica now a drain on my cutting?

Tags: cuttings

I took several cuttings last year of a 9 foot fatsia japonica in my garden. A cutting has rooted and in the last 2 weeks has sprouted 6 new leaves at the top of the cutting. Are the old large leaves now a drain on this small cutting? Should I trim them and allow the plant to depend on it's new growth?[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, leave them alone, they're busy carrying out photosynthesis and assisting in the new growth. If they turn brown or tatty later on when the new  growth has grown on well, then remove them if you want.